# JPackage and Camera Permission

Tags: macos, permissions, jvm, jpackage

I have this Java app that requires Camera permission to run video streams from webcams.

It works well on most OSes (Windows/Linux etc..) except on MacOS when double clicking on the icon.

It actually works when I execute the binary inside the .app file from the terminal, as seen below:

[image]

I am guessing that's because Terminal/iTerm have camera permissions.

I do have:

```
        <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
        <string>My application needs access to the camera to perform XYZ.</string>
```

in all the Info.plist files possible, but to no avail. Any idea ?